# How to call controller method without Area name in url in .net 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, migration, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have registered an Area in .net core 3.1 and using [Area("AreaName")] above the controller method.
Now i want to call a method without having AreaName before the controller name.
Is there any way of calling .

Without Area Name -

https://localhost:12345/EmailService/GetEmailList

```
public class EmailServiceController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
    {

  public async Task<JsonResult> GetEmailList()
        {
          
}
}

with area name - 
[Area("AreaName")]
public class EmailServiceController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
    {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to call a method without having AreaName before the
> controller name. Is there any way of calling .
>
> Without Area Name -
>
> https://localhost:12345/EmailService/GetEmailList

Try to use the `[HttpGet]` or `[Route]` attribute, and place them on the Action method.

For example:

```
[Area("Email")]
public class EmailServiceController : Controller
{
    // GET: EmailServiceController
    //[HttpGet("EmailService/Index")]
    [Route("EmailService/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    } 
}
```

Then the request url will be: `https://localhost:44393/EmailService/Index`

[image]